# In what region this function converges uniformly?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the problem, which is :

Find in what regions, $\frac z{e^{nz}}$ is uniformly convergent and pointwise convergent?

According to the answer, this function converges uniformly at $Re(z)\ge \epsilon >0$. and converges pointwise at $Re(z)>0$.

But if consider $z=0$, it is certainly 0. Then this function converges pointwise at 0. However the region of the answer given in the book doesn't contain 0.

Also, in the case of uniform convergence, consider the region, $\epsilon > Re(z) \ge  0$ and $Im(z)=0$. (That is, $z$ is real.)

Then $|\frac z {e^{nz}}| \le |z| \le \epsilon$.

But the answer does not contain this region neither.

Could you explain why the given answer is right? and where my reasoning fails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that pointwise convergence holds at some points not in the region $\Re z >0$.

Your argument for uniform convergence is  not correct. To prove uniform convergence you need $|z/e^{nz}| <\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large, for **every** $\epsilon >0$. If you define your region in terms of a fixed $\epsilon$ you cannot get convergence.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer. The answer I wrote was given in the back of the book. then do you think the answer written in the text wrong?

Comment: For uniform convergence the answer given is correct.  It appears that for ponitwise convergence only convergence to $0$ was considered.